# tab stop skipping over last field in jQuery Pop-up

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple jQuery pop-up window with 4 fields displayed. When I tab from one field to the next, the tab will not stop in the last field, it skips straight to the first one. In this example the tab will not stop in the "**DDLPMStartMonth**" dropdownList. It does not matter what type of control the last field in the pop-up is as I have similar pop-ups that have the same problem where the last field is a simple text box.

Unfortunately I cannot upload images yet

link to picture of form: [pop-up message](http://www.flickr.com/photos/119541458@N08/)

Any suggestions to to what might be causing this behaviour?

HTML is shown below:

```
<div id="dvPMpopupEditor" class="MainPopUp" style="display: none">
    <div class="popupTitleBar-purple">
        <div class="title">
            <h2><label id="lblHeadingLabel">Add Membership</label></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="close" onclick="CancelPopupSettings()" >
            <span class="dashboardIcons closeIcon"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popupContent">
        <div class="required MembershipAdded" style="display:none; float:left;">Membership added.</div>
        <div class="required fr">* indicates required field</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="PMOrderHiddenField" CssClass="PMOrderHiddenField" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="PMUserIDHiddenField" CssClass="PMUserIDHiddenField" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="PMPDEVIDHiddenField" CssClass="PMPDEVIDHiddenField" runat="server" Style="display: none" />

        <!-- MembershipName-->
        <div>
            <span class="frmlabel">

                <asp:Label ID="NameOfInstitutionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtMembershipName" Text="Name of professional body:" />
                <span class="frmrequired">*</span>
            </span>
            <div class="fl">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipName" CssClass="width300 txtMembershipName" runat="server"  MaxLength="100" />
                <div class="mandatory MembershipNameRequired" style="display:none">Please enter an membership Name.</div>
<%--                <br /><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revMembershipName" CssClass="required revMembershipName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMembershipName" ErrorMessage="Please only use alphanumeric characters" ValidationExpression="^((?!&#)[A-Za-z0-9-' .,/\\])*$" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" />--%>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /MembershipName-->

        <!--MembershipStatus-->
        <div>
            <span class="frmlabel">

                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtMembershipStatus" Text="Membership Status:" />
                <span class="frmrequired">*</span>
            </span>
            <div class="fl">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMembershipStatus" CssClass="width300 txtMembershipStatus" runat="server"  MaxLength="50" />
                <div class="mandatory MembershipStatusRequired" style="display:none">Please enter your membership status.</div>
<%--                <br /><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revMembershipStatus" CssClass="required revMembershipStatus" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMembershipStatus" ErrorMessage="Please only use alphanumeric characters" ValidationExpression="^((?!&#)[A-Za-z0-9-' .,/\\])*$" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" />--%>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <!--/MembershipStatus-->


        <%--Start Date--%>
        <span class="frmlabel">
            <asp:Label ID="StartDateLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="DDLPMStartMonth" Text="Date Membership commenced:" />
            <span class="frmrequired">*</span>
        </span>
        <div class="fl">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPMStartMonth" DataSourceID="dsMonths" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Key" runat="server" CssClass="profileB-DDL DDLPMStartMonth"/>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsMonths" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetListForDropDown" TypeName="Eteach.Workflow.Lookup">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Month" Name="name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Month" Name="pleaseSelectKey" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPMStartYear" runat="server" CssClass="profileB-DDL DDLPMStartYear" />
            <div class="required PMStartDateRequired" style="display:none">Please enter a commencement date.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <%--/Start Date--%>



    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="PopupButton">
        <div class="fr">
            <div class="fl marRight10">
                <a href="#" id="SaveandAddImgBtn" class="btn btn-main btn-reg" alt="SaveAndAddNew" onclick="AddMembership('new')" >Save and add another entry</a>
            </div>
            <div class="fl marRight10">
                <a href="#" id="SaveImgBtn" class="btn btn-second btn-reg btn-width" alt="Save" onclick="AddMembership()" >Save</a>
            </div>
            <div class="fl">
                <a href="#" id="CancelImgBtn" class="btn btn-second btn-reg btn-width" alt="Exit" onclick="CancelPopupSettings()" >Cancel</a>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Code to display pop-up
    function ShowPMBlock(UIID) {

```
    $.blockUI({
        message: $("#dvPMpopupEditor"),
        title: 'Add Membership',
        theme: false,
        css: { background: 'none', border: 'none', top: GetBlockUITopWithSize(600), width: '800px', margin: 'auto', left: GetBlockUILeftWithSize(800), cursor: 'default' },
        overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#000', opacity: '0.5', cursor: 'default' }
    });
}

function GetBlockUITopWithSize(iSize) {
    var i = 0;
    i = ($(window).height() - iSize) / 2;
    return i;
}

function GetBlockUILeftWithSize(iSize) {
    var i = 0;
    i = ($(window).width() - iSize) / 2;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: the tab is most likely moving focus to a control on the page which is outside the overlay div.. please provide code. a JSFiddle would be perfect.

Comment: I still have this problem - any idea's????